# Is there a way to reduce the priority of camera thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a scenario that is I have to send data along with the real time video. The data which we are sending is a ppt on a separate thread. But the problem I am facing is that camera is taking whole of the cpu's cycle since it by default has a high priority over other threads, so our data is not being sent at all. We would like to keep varying the priorties of both threads so that both gets loaded fast enough or lower the priority of the camera every .25 seconds. Is there any way in which i can do?

I do not know much about threads other than its basics.pls help.Thanks in advance.